# How to access the system clock in C#

Tags: c#

How to access the system clock in C#? I want to use system clock for time delay purpose instead of using thread.sleep();.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you wanting to change the time or just read the time, etc ...

Comment: what do you mean, what do you want to do? do you want the date/time or do you want to be able to set the clock? can you add more details?

Comment: How do you intend to use the system clock for time delay? do you mean (while time_to_wait_until > DateTime.Now.Ticks){ //do nothing }???

Comment: Ugh... bracket in the wrong place... please don't judge me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
```

will get you the current time.

So if you want to `sleep` until a specific time you can use the `TimeSpan` to calculate the number of milliseconds until then. You still will need to use `thread.sleep` or better still [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) (or [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)) to pause the process.

If, however, you want to start a process at a specific time, you'd be better off creating a separate application and creating a scheduled task to control it. This is accessed via the Control Panel.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is not a good idea. Use System.Treading.Timer instead.

Answer (score 10):

Your best bet for delay purposes instead of sleep is to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).  You set it for a how often you want it to "tick" and you get events when that happens.

Comment: I'm not certain, but doesn't the Timer use thread.sleep in the backend?

Comment: The WinForms timer uses WM_TIMER messages.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [DateTime struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(vs.71).aspx) and the [DateTime.Now property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(VS.71).aspx)?

```
DateTime.Now;
```